# How to convert 'e' formatted numbers for heatmap plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap from the a data matrix.

Ouput from dput()

```
structure(c(0.00770980703597275, -7.12796126152078e-05, 0.0724376220577931, 0.455109944735237, 0.290854227402422, 0.197017216743111), .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(
c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3"), c("Day0", "Day1")))
```

However, putting the matrix through this heatmap code leads to an error.

```
heatmap(DM, scale="column", cexRow=1.5,
    labRow=paste(rownames(DM),sep=""),
    col= colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Blues"))(25))
```

[image]

Gene 3 should be lower at Day0 and increase at Day1, however because the numbers are 'e' formatted (7.243762e-02) this is confusing `heatmap`.

How can I convert the data matrix numbers into a format that is more compatible with `heatmap`?

I tried playing with `formatC` to do this, but with not much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather because of your `scale="column"` - values are re-centered within the column (i.e. Day), so you can see the difference between samples but not between days.

Comment: Yes, this should be replaced by `scale = "none"`. Might be best to include that in the answer here.